# template10 : resizer doesn't focus on tab key pressed

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I use a resizer control from template10 library in ma uwp xaml page.
When i tap on tab key on my keyboard, focus is going to next input on my form, but when I arrive to resizer control, focus is lost.

```
<TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            Width="500" Height="30"
            Text="{Binding ContactForm.Subject, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<controls:Resizer Margin="0,0,0,24">
    <TextBox    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                MinWidth="500" MinHeight="100"
                Text="{Binding ContactForm.Message, Mode=TwoWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </TextBox>
</controls:Resizer>
```

Does anyone know how to keep focus on textbox inclued on resizer control by pressing tab key ?

Answer (score 1):

When you tap the "Tab", the `TextBox` in `Resizer`can get focus. But you need to tap three times "Tab" to make the `TextBox` in `Resizer` to get focus.

If you want to keep focus on `TextBox` inclued on `Resizer` control by pressing tab key, you should be able to set `False` to [`IsTabStop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_IsTabStop) property of the `Resizer` control and set `False` to `IsTabStop` property of the `ContentControl` in `Resizer`'s template. If IsTabStop is false, the control is excluded from tab navigation and the control cannot receive input focus.

To modify the template of `Resizer`, we can select the `Resizer` in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Template**"→ "**Edit a Copy...**".

Comment: Thank you Jayden.
You are right, but i can't edit template. The only choice given is "create from empty...".
Do you know if i there is another solution ?

Comment: Hi Jayden, found how to edit a copy by updating to VS2017.
But if i do it i have only ControlTemplate generated. Where can i find the template content to edit ?